# GCloud: recover closed session

Tags: session, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I have created a VM with Google Cloud Engine.
I connect to it via the SSH button in the platform as shown here.

[image: the platform]

This created a new window with which I have used the VM.

The problem is that I have closed this window a couple of times by mistake.
And thus I have opened a new sesssion via the same method.

I'm worried that this has left some sessions open.  How can I track them down?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you launched a `session` type program (screen, tmux, etc.) during your SSH session, programs started by your SSH session are terminated when your session is closed. There are no background sessions to worry about (usually).

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks.  I actually did knew how to recover the tmux session.  The concern was only about the other instance running there somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you close the window by clicking the `X` button on top right corner that session is being terminated. I have tested it with an ubuntu VM instance.

If you want to test it your self:
You can click on `SSH` twice and it will open two different windows. Run the `who` command and it will show you all the active sessions of that instance. You will see `[USERNAME] pts/0 [DATE] [TIME] ([IP_ADDRESS])` and `[USERNAME] pts/1 [DATE] [TIME] ([IP_ADDRESS])`. Close one of the windows and run again the `who` command on the one that it is still open. You will now see only one record. So the sessions are being terminated whenever you close the SSH window.